# Why is the "Manage Extensibility" tool missing from Admin Tools

Tags: desire2learn

I'm trying to get started with Valence 2.0.

As per instructions I'm supposed to click on the "Manage Extensibility" tool under Admin Tools. This does not seem to exist anywhere. We're running D2L v9.4.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

There is a permission called "Manage Extensibility" that controls the visibility of the Manage Extensibility tool. You may be able to adjust that.

If not, I would open a support ticket to Desire2Learn it you are having server/config issues.